# Spring MVC application not synchronized

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, thread-safety

In my spring MVC application we have a below issue. We are new to spring and using spring 3.x. Will explain the problem below, please comment if not clear.

- When we trigger concurrent requests at same time to below service and
  Repository bean, the SampleBean object shown in below code is getting
  overridden with the request that triggers later.
- In other words the values of the SampleBean in Thread 1 is getting
  overridden with values of SampleBean in Thread 2.

Skeleton code as follows with comments.

> MyService.java

```
@Service public class MyService {
        @Autowired  private SampleBean sampleBean;
        @Autowired  private MyDao myDao;
        public void updateDetailsToDB() throws Exception {
           sampleBean.setXXX("xxx");
           sampleBean.setYYY("yyy");
           myDao.updateDetailsToDB(sampleBean);
        }
    }
```

> MyDao.java

```
@Repository 
public class MyDao {
    @Autowired  private SampleBean sampleBean;
    @Autowired  private MyDao myDao;
    public void updateDetailsToDB(SampleBean sampleBean) throws Exception {
       //Step 1: Print the data in sampleBean to console - *At this point the the sampleBean object prints the correct value specific to the thread.*
       //Step 2: Insert data to table 1 into db using **jdbcTemplate**, the data will be taken from the bean 
         sampleBean getters.
       //Step 3: Print the data in sampleBean to console.- *At this point the sampleBean value always print the values of the second request and it overwrites the value of the bean in first request as well which is not the case in Step 1.*
       //Step 4: Insert data to table 2
    }
}
```

Update:
If i add **synchronized** to the method in service class then every thing works fine as the requests are being processed one by one. How to fix this without adding **synchronized**.

Comment: You shouldn't keep state in a singleton, your design is flawed. Your `SampleBean` shouldn't be there. It should only exists as a method argument, preferably annotated with `@ModelAttribute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Service in MyService by default is singleton and so is SampleBean. You can try to change the SampleBean scope from singleton to another. Maybe the better way is not using instance variable of SampleBean, instead create a new instance for each updateDetailsToDB method request of MyService.
--Thanks HaoChih

Answer (score -1):

Actually your design is wrong since you are using instance variable.
But using `@Scope("prototype")` or @Scope("request") (if it is web app) in your MyService class you can make it work.

Comment: As i am using @Service in MyService by default it will be singleton right?

Comment: @prabu you are right.  @Service in MyService by default is singleton and so is SampleBean. You can try to change the SampleBean scope from singleton to another. Maybe the better way is not using instance variable of SampleBean, instead create a new instance for each `updateDetailsToDB` method request of MyService.